# windows shell, move multiple file arguments error

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

```
f:\i>move foo bar dir
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

help move says:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination
```

This seems to imply multiple arguments. So how can I give multiple arguments to move?

Comment: Stobors comment below indicates the syntax was removed from XP and later.  If you think about it, MS screwed this up: filenames can have commas in them, so if you have three files, which I delimit with quotes: "file1"  "file2" and "file1,file2", then what does "move file1,file2 someDir" mean?  Problem is, the syntax should have been: "move [/Y | /-Y] filename1 [filename2 ...] destination".  Yes, filenames can have spaces, but then you delimit your filenames on the command line with quotes, and all works well.  Point is, each filename must be a separate avgv entry to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for %i in (foo bar) do @move %i dir
```

Or, in a cmd file (since the use of `%` variables is slightly different there):

```
for %%i in (foo bar) do @move %%i dir
```

Comment: Get over your programming language bias. If this were about an argument to a C file move function, it would be programming? Both go in a file as part of a program, which is programming.

Comment: I have no language bias, Ian, I was just pointing out that, if you're asking how to move files from the command prompt, that' NOT programming-related and the question will be closed. If it's done as part of a cmd script, it IS programming. Some of my best code has been written in bash/cmd.

Comment: Ok, you have a console bias. You can program on the console. Unlike this question, everything valid in a bash script is also valid on the command line. Also, ZSH has good multi-line editing capabilities, so theres no reason not to write a complete program as a function on the console and then paste it into a file if you want to save your work. Powershell ISE has a console built in it that also has multi-line editing abilities.

Comment: I don't understand where you're coming from here, @Ian, especially with a two month gap :-) I've just stated that questions just relating to Windows commands are likely to be closed. *I* won't close them since you're right - quite a bit of my shell development is on the command line then just cut and pasted into a script. Even Windows, though it tends to be one command at a time there, unlike bash. In any case, your question survived, possibly *because* you made it clear it was for a script. My information was to point out the difference between % and %% in how you run it.

Comment: Since the answer seems to be troubling you, I'll just remove the phrase you seem concerned about. No offense intended or taken. I hope that's better.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the privilege to download stuffs, you can use [GNU coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html),

```
c:test> mv foo bar destination
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple files to the move command as the first argument, separate them with commas:

```
move foo,bar dir
```

That's why there's a comma in the help:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination
```

Comment: That gives the exact same message, syntax incorrect. mkdir foo bar dir, then do that command, you will see.

Comment: Apparently that syntax was dropped in xp and newer... It used to work in win2k and before. I don't know why it's still listed in the docs. :-S

Comment: If the multi-file syntax really was removed in XP and later, the best option is probably to create a CMD file using the commands I've given in my answer (suitably adjusted to handle spaces in the filename if need be).